# Is there any problem with implementing a tristate buffer this way?

Tags: vlsi, digital-buffer

Consider the following implementation of an *inverting* tristate buffer in CMOS:

[image]

My textbook (Weste and Harris's *CMOS VLSI Design*) says that to implement a (noninverting) tristate buffer we should *precede* this inverting buffer with a regular inverter. My question is whether there is any reason that this order should matter. That is, is there any reason we should prefer the inverter-inverting buffer order to the inverting buffer-inverter order? These functionally do the same thing, but perhaps there is some power argument which I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "Z" input to an ordinary inverter doesn't produce a "Z" output.

The line being at high impedance means its voltage can drift randomly due to leakage, stray fields, cross-talk from other wires, etc. The 2nd-stage inverter then responds to that essentially random voltage and produces either a high or a low output, not a high-impedance output.

In the worst case scenario, with parasitic feedback from the output back to the input, the 2nd stage might oscillate, consuming large amounts of power and possibly even damaging the chip.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of a tri-state buffer is that you have three states: "1", "0", and "Hi-Z" (i.e. floating).  if you put a normal inverter on the output rather than the input, then you have an inverter with a floating input when EN is low.  If the high Z node happens to be mid-rail, you have huge amounts of cross conduction (since both devices are on), and if it's not, you have an output with an undefined, low impedance state.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. If I'm understanding you correctly, you're saying that in the Z output state we can't be certain of the actual voltage on there (why is this? If it was 0 or 1 before, won't it remain there when we go to Z...or is there leakage)? If so, then I follow the issue with contention current if the Z node is mid-rail. But I don't follow your other comment. Are you saying that if it's \$V_{DD}\$ or \$GND\$ and we don't know which then our overall buffer output is at \$GND\$ or \$V_{DD}\$, respectively, and that this unknown is a problem?